# outside something/outside of something

Tags: prepositions

> The boss is not in, he is in a meeting outside the room.
>
> The boss is not in, he is in a meeting outside of the room.

Do they mean the same?

Comment: You are outside a building when you paint the outside **of** the building.

Comment: It sounds as though the meeting were in the corridor just outside the room! You would say _elsewhere, in another room_, or simply leave it to be assumed that the meeting was not here.

Comment: Which one of them sounds that way? The question is what the difference between them is.

Comment: Both of them sound that way. _Outside of_ is apparently more used in the US. See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9700/outside-or-outside-of).